# ¿Como validar un numero de telefono de españa(o de cualquier otra parte) y validar un nombre con dos apellidos mediante expresiones regulares?

Tags: javascript, regex

Como pone en el titulo tengo dos xpresiones regulares que deben validar un nombre y numero de telefono de españa.
El nombre nose cuantas veces lo habre cambiado que sigue sin pasarme los parametros de forma correcta ya que debe contener un nombre y sus dos apellidos. Y al intentar validar un numero de telefono aparece un error que pone "SyntaxError: nothing to repeat", pero no veo el fallo sintactico, a continuacion paso el codigo

```
       var telef = new RegExp("^(\+34|0034|34)?[6789]\d{8}$");
        var valortelef = document.getElementById("c7").value;
        if (telef.test(valortelef)) {
            console.log("valor correcto");
            cliente.settelef(valortelef);
        } else {
            console.log("iNTRODUCE OTRO VALOR" + telef);
        }

      var nombre = new RegExp("(([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\s*)([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\s*)([A-Z][a-z]*)){3,30}"); 
      if(nombre.test(valornombre)){
         console.log("valor correcto");
         misclientes.push(new cliente(nombre));
         cliente.setNombre(valorNombre);
     }else{
         console.log("iNTRODUCE OTRO VALOR" + valornombre);
     }
```

y html:

```
        Nombre:<input type="text" id="c1" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" />
        
        Telefono:<input type="text" id="c7" name="telefono" placeholder="numero con el +34 por favor">
        <br>
```

Comment: ¿Sabes que en HTML5 ya puedes usar pattern para definir expresiones regulares en determinado campos `input` ?  Por ejemplo `<input id="telNo" name="telNo" type="tel" required pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}">` (eso para un telefono), o bien `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]+">` para texto. Lo digo para evitar tanta comprobacion via javascript si no es estrictamente necesaria.

Comment: @masterguru, si lose pero debo poner todo el codigo en la pestaña de javascript, html debe llevar lo minimo

Comment: Falta código. No veo que valides eso de ningun modo. Tal como lo tienes se carga al inicio pero luego como lo validas de nuevo?  No hay ni un triste boton para ello ni un evento a la escucha.  Ponlo para que no pensemos que tenemos que hacerlo todo nosotros, haz tu parte mostrandonos un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el segundo comentario se muestra el error. Necesitas poner dos veces `\\` para escapar el signo + y otras dos para todos los dígitos `\d` del regex.

En el segundo patrón del código lo tienes bien con el `\\s`, pero no se activa si no pones los límites en `{1,30}`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("enviar").onclick = function() {
    console.clear();
    /* var telef = new RegExp('^(\+34|0034|34)?[6789]\d{8}$');*/
    /* El error:                 ^                   ^        */
    var telef = new RegExp("^(\\+34|0034|34)?[6789]\\d{8}$");
    var valortelef = document.getElementById("c7").value;
    if (telef.test(valortelef)) {
      console.log("valor correcto");
    } else {
      console.log("INTRODUCE OTRO VALOR. EJ: +34666555444");
    }

    var nombre = new RegExp("(([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\s*)([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\s*)([A-Z][a-z]*)){1,30}");
    valornombre = document.getElementById("c1").value;
    if (nombre.test(valornombre)) {
      console.log("valor correcto");
    } else {
      console.log("INTRODUCE OTRO VALOR. EJ: John Doe Due");
    }
  };
};
```

```html
Nombre:<input type="text" id="c1" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" value="John Doe Due" />
<br><br>
Telefono:<input type="text" id="c7" name="telefono" placeholder="numero con el +34 por favor" value="+34666555444" />
<br><br>
<button type="button" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

A tener en consideración:

- El patrón del teléfono es bastante estático.
  **Admite:**
  +34666555444
  0034666555444
  34666555444
  666555444
  **Pero no admite:**
  +34 666 555 444
  +34 666 55 54 44
  0034 666 555 444
  0034 666 55 54 44
  34 666 555 444
  34 666 55 54 44
  666 555 444
  666 55 54 44
- El patrón del nombre es bastante estático en los tres fragmentos **OJO CON ESTO**.
  **Admite:**
  John Doe Due
  John Doe Due Doe
  <script>alert('yeah!!!')</script>John Doe Due Doe
  John Doe Due Doe<script>alert('yeah!!!')</script>
  **Pero no admite:**
  José Domínguez Cigüeña
  Domingo Del Campo Ñaño García
  Ángel Rodríguez Vermúdez

Una posible solución para los números de teléfono sería esta:
`^(?:(?:\+?[0-9]{2,4})?[ ]?[6789][0-9 ]{8,13})$`
https://regex101.com/r/53MXY4/1
Para los formatos de números de España serviría. Para otros países habría que ver los formatos de cada uno y rehacer el patrón.

Una posible solución para los nombres sería esta:
`^(?:(?:(?:[A-Z][a-zÀ-Ƶ]*){1,10}(?:\s*))+)(?:[A-Z][a-zÀ-Ƶ]*){1,10}$`
https://regex101.com/r/TN73xB/1